# Rerun Oozie infinitely when fail

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have a Workflow Oozie 4.3 with one Action that contains a Shell :

```
<action name="KafkaToADLS" retry-max="10" retry-interval="1">
```

This will rerun the workflow 1 minute after a fail, and will do this 10 times.

Is there something to do to make the workflow rerun infinitely, after each fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot specify an infinite number of retries. On the other hand it's an integer number, so you can specify a big enough number which will work effectively as infinite.

*To be honest, I don't think it's a good idea to specify too huge retry-max values.*